# How to compare multiple boolean value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, series

I have a df like this:

```
         customer_id                       offer_id                   viewed_withintime completed_withintime
0   389bc3fa690240e798340f5a15918d5c    f19421c1d4aa40978ebb69ca19b0e20d    True           True
1   389bc3fa690240e798340f5a15918d5c    f19421c1d4aa40978ebb69ca19b0e20d    True           False
2   389bc3fa690240e798340f5a15918d5c    f19421c1d4aa40978ebb69ca19b0e20d    True           False
```

I wanted to create a new column called `offer_succussful`, if both `viewed_withintime` and `completed_withintime` are `True`, then the value for `offer_succussful` is `1`, otherwise it's `0`.

Here's my code:

```
# label offer_successful to 1 if an offer is viewed and completed within offer_endtime, if not, set it to 0
offer_success_merge['offer_successful'] = (offer_success_merge['completed_withintime'] == True) and (offer_success_merge['viewed_withintime'] == True)
```

This returns error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can someone have a look for me, not sure how to modify this piece of code...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the numpy module to solve the problem:

```
import numpy as np
offer_success_merge['offer_successful'] = np.logical_and((offer_success_merge['completed_withintime'] == True), (offer_success_merge['viewed_withintime'] == True))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
df['offer_successful'] = (df['viewed_withintime']== True) & (df['completed_withintime']== True)
```